# While loop and outputting math operators

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I'm trying to create a while loop that outputs a list of values, adds them together, and outputs a total with an "=" sign at the end
I.e., if the User enters the numbers 5 and 12, the output would show up like this:
5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 + 11 + 12 = total

This is how my 'while' loop looks right now:

```
while(enteredNum1 <= enteredNum2){
    total += enteredNum1;
    document.write(enteredNum1 + " + ");
    enteredNum1++;
}

document.write("= " + total);
```

I know it will always append the " + ", but can anyone point me in the right direction for having the last value show "=" instead of the "+" again?

Comment: you could write the plus separate to `enteredNum1` and check if the loop will run again, if it will write the `+` otherwise carry on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any easy way would be an if statement checking if the loop will continue:

```
while(enteredNum1 <= enteredNum2) {
    total += enteredNum1;
    if (enteredNum1 + 1 <= enteredNum2) {
        document.write(enteredNum1 + " + ");
    } else {
        document.write(enteredNum1);
    }

    enteredNum1++;
}

document.write(" = " + total);
```

Alternatively, saving the output as a string and taking the "+" off using `substring` would work as well

Comment: Thank you, SuckerForMayhem!
Never considered using an if/else within the while loop!

Comment: Consider using an array instead of calling many times document.write and increase complexity with if/else. See below.

Comment: @KyleK I agree, using an array and `join` is better, this was just a simple alteration

Answer (score 5):

Alternative;

```
var numbers = [];
while(enteredNum1 <= enteredNum2){
    total += enteredNum1;
    numbers.push(enteredNum1++);
}

document.write(numbers.join(" + ") + " = " + total);
```

Answer (score 1):

Proper way:

```
list = [];
total = 0;
enteredNum1 = parseInt(enteredNum1); // parseInt only if enteredNum1 can be a string
while(enteredNum1 <= enteredNum2) {
    total += enteredNum1;
    list.push(enteredNum1);
    enteredNum1++;
}

document.write(list.join(" + ") + " = " + total);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
total += enteredNum1;
document.write(enteredNum1);
enteredNum1++;

while(enteredNum1 <= enteredNum2){
    total += enteredNum1;
    document.write(" + " + enteredNum1);
    enteredNum1++;
}

document.write("= " + total);
```